# Unwanted delay before requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, requestanimationframe

An interesting case where IE actually runs the way I want :-) I made this function to do SVG animations via requestAnimationFrame (for this example I omitted the value calculations, etc ... but my first experiment was to animate a change to the 'fill' attribute of an SVG rect). Anyways, IE runs the animation nice and speedily ... but all other browsers have a noticeable delay before they run the animation. Almost like those browsers need to "spin up" an engine to handle this each time ... also I looked at some other examples online and some of the animations seemed "choppy". I suppose I could use requestAnimationFrame for IE and CSS3 keyframes for other browsers :-( don't really want to. Am I missing something? Why the delay before the animation plays?

```
animateViaRequestAnimationFrame = function() { // 

    var duration = arguments[0].duration;

    // requestAnimationFrame is ~60 frames/second
    var quantityFrameCalls = parseInt((duration/1000)*60);

    i = 1;
    function callFrame(){

        // here, bunch of values math and updating the target element properties 

        i++;
        if (i < quantityFrameCalls+1) {
            requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                callFrame();    
            });
        } // if

    } // callFrame

    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        callFrame();    
    });

}; // animateViaRequestAnimationFrame
```

Comment: Oops, thanks Ben, yeah the start of the callFrame function would help wouldn't it :-) I do have some loops to convert hex values but I don't think those are the slowdown since they console.log instantaneously and then the animation plays after a delay. I suppose I'm just wondering if there's some magic mojo to working with requestAnimationFrame in browsers other than IE

Comment: Just a very simple tip, when you do `requestAnimationFrame(function(){ callFrame(); });` you can actually just do `requestAnimationFrame(callFrame);`

Comment: Thanks Patrick yes I did try that way also.

Comment: I dont think the code causing the problem is in your snippet. RAF might run at a bunch of different frame rates by the way, so counting frames might not be what you want. My first idea would be to check the easing function...

Comment: Perhaps I should try web workers? Perhaps use one web worker to run my value calculations and another web worker to play the animation? Or... am I supposed to instantiate some sort of player object?

Comment: LOL ummm, I didn't implement the easing yet! Hmmm... maybe I'll try the web worker approach and see if it does anything to eliminate/reduce the delay before the animation plays. I'll keep everyone posted.

Comment: As a test, I moved the values math to a web worker. There was much less of a delay before the animation started, but still a delay. Again, IE played the animation instantaneously in both scenarios. Perhaps RAF isn't ready for primetime just yet ... unless there's something I don't know about the pre-delay. It seems like browsers are queuing the RAFs then playing it when all other js is done ... I don't think this matters but I didn't assign the RAF to a var, I didn't cancel it. Perhaps I should try that. Anyways, considering setIntervals for animating the SVG.

Comment: Added the var assignment, also added window.requestAnimationFrame, also added an explicit window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestAnimationFrameID); in my limiter conditional. Still the delay before the animation starts.

Comment: It's like each callFrame iteration is slower then the screen repaint, so RAF queues the requests until all loops complete.

Comment: Just tested previous comment theory by super-optimizing the loop values math. Still the delay...

Comment: AHA. This is something to do with SVG. I applied the same animation to a DIV and there was no pre-animation delay. So now I need to figure out if I can change something about the SVG animation code to make it occur immediately. I'm using jquery's attr('fill',hexvalue) in each loop, however perhaps a transform attr will work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG. By mistake, I had left a css transition on the test rect that delayed the transition. So, Ben was correct :-) Well, at least I have a super cool web worker enabled RAF animation function now. DOH